# Error: A valid Auth0 Client Secret must be provided on Vercel

Tags: next.js, auth0

Hello I'm trying to deploy aplication on vercel, on preview everything works perfectly, however on production it fails with this error. I'm using `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` version `^0.16.1`

```sh
08:18:12.508    > Build error occurred
08:18:12.510    Error: A valid Auth0 Client Secret must be provided
08:18:12.510        at Object.createInstance [as default] (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/instance.node.js:16:15)
08:18:12.510        at initAuth0 (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/index.js:9:46)
```

The auth0 config file, looks same as the official docs.

```
import { initAuth0 } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default initAuth0({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: 'openid profile',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  session: {
    // The secret used to encrypt the cookie.
    cookieSecret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    // The cookie lifetime (expiration) in seconds. Set to 8 hours by default.
    cookieLifetime: 60 * 60 * 8,
    // (Optional) The cookie domain this should run on. Leave it blank to restrict it to your domain.
    cookieDomain: 'your-domain.com',
    // (Optional) SameSite configuration for the session cookie. Defaults to 'lax', but can be changed to 'strict' or 'none'. Set it to false if you want to disable the SameSite setting.
    cookieSameSite: 'lax',
    // (Optional) Store the id_token in the session. Defaults to false.
    storeIdToken: false,
    // (Optional) Store the access_token in the session. Defaults to false.
    storeAccessToken: false,
    // (Optional) Store the refresh_token in the session. Defaults to false.
    storeRefreshToken: false
  },
  oidcClient: {
    // (Optional) Configure the timeout in milliseconds for HTTP requests to Auth0.
    httpTimeout: 2500,
    // (Optional) Configure the clock tolerance in milliseconds, if the time on your server is running behind.
    clockTolerance: 10000
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `env` variable `clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET` was disabled on production build somehow.